# Copy files recursively from source to target based on wildcard using Python

Tags: python

I have a source directory that has several xml files in nested location. I am trying to write a python script to copy files recursively based on a pattern (say *1.2.3.xml) to a target location.

```
source
├── master.1.2.3.xml
    └── directory
           └── fileA.1.2.3.xml
           ├── fileA.1.2.5.xml
           ├── fileB.1.2.3.xml
```

Expected outcome:

```
target
├── master.1.2.3.xml
    └── directory
           └── fileA.1.2.3.xml
           ├── fileB.1.2.3.xml
```

The following script doesn't do the filtering.

```
from shutil import copytree
def ignored_files(adir,filenames):
    return [filename for filename in filenames if not filename.endswith('1.2.3.xml')]
copytree(source, target, ignore=ignored_files)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil%20ignore_patterns#shutil.ignore_patterns ?

Comment: Can you give us the exact source and target you're using? And what is the outcome? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 3):

What is happening here is that the copytree function will work recursively. First, it will descend into source and give `ignored_files()`  two items for filenames arg - `[master.1.2.3.xml, directory]`

The ignored_files will return `[directory]` as it does not match with the pattern and thus copytree will ignore the entire directory itself.

You will have to add an additional check for directories in your condition in `ignored_files()` something like `os.path.isdir()`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this?

```
import glob
import shutil
dest_dir = "path/to/dir"
for file in glob.glob(r'/path/to/dir/*1.2.3.xml'):
    print(file)
    shutil.copy(file, dest_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
def copy_tree_with_wildcards(src: str, dest: str, pattern: str):
src = os.path.abspath(src)
for filename in glob.iglob(src + '/**/' + pattern, recursive=True):
    src_file = os.path.join(src, filename)
    dest_file = dest + filename[len(src):]
    dest_dir = os.path.dirname(dest_file)
    os.makedirs(dest_dir, exist_ok=True)
    if os.path.isfile(src_file):
        shutil.copy(src_file, dest_file)
```